# What's the risk of interacting with a social engineer?

Tags: phishing, spam, social-engineering

I received a WhatsApp message. [image: message]

I never registed with any recruitment job portal, or even speak Arabic at all

What are the dangers in myself trying to find out what happened (did they send the same message to everyone, did they get my number somewhere?)

I feel there is potential danger in interacting with them but I don't understand the risk. I want to understand the risks of interacting with them (maybe the only risk is the risk to waste my time).

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150999/discussion-on-question-by-george-ntoulos-whats-the-risk-of-interacting-with-a-s); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

This is less likely to be the result of a breach and more likely to be related to companies which regularly collect information and create a profile on you (i.e. advertisement companies), or even job boards (e.g. Glassdoor) or social media.  Well, I suppose this information may stem from some data leak, but just knowing a little about you alone isn't indicative of your information being included in a compromise.

I wouldn't necessarily call this "dangerous" but more just spam. If you want to see what kind of information may be out there in actual leaks, I would start with sites like haveibeenpwned.

Comment: But they don't know much beyond the Telephone Number. I don't speak Arabic, I have no relation, no history with Asia.

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos I don't know why you are fixating on the language thing. That's only an indication that they don't actually know anything about you.

Comment: @schroeder Which means there is something fishy. I hope my guess that there was a leak (or worse a breach) can be considered informed.

Comment: How is it "informed"? What is it informed by? It's a conclusion without basis, only fear.

Comment: @schroeder Informed by the only information I actually have. The content of the message. The message is from a supposed recruiter but I am not looking for a job at all. The message offers to give details in Arabic but I don't speak Arabic. I am not finding anything on Bos Staffing (there appears no organization with that name) operating in Greece with my Google Fu. The basis is they have been wrong about my person (and are probably lying) but what is true is that somehow they have my telephone number. How? The fear is about interacting with them. Is it safe? Is the only risk wasting my time?

Comment: No, I would not interact with them, because, as you said, they are saying stuff about Arabic, etc. so what will probably happen (if I had to guess) is that this will end in a scam where they request you to pay an "application fee" or similar to be offered the job.  This has absolutely no information which indicates the information they gathered came from a data breach.  Here, try this - Google your name and see what information you can gather about yourself just from Google.  It's probably not nothing and can help you be more private online.

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos so, like I said at the start, your question is "what's the risk of interacting with a social engineer?" And that has nothing to do with a "leak" or an investigation. This is a pure, plain recruitment scam.

Comment: And this is BOS: https://www.google.com/search?q=bos+staffing+global+recruitment+agency+greece in "Athens".

Answer (score 1):

The primary risk is that you will confirm that your WhatsApp number is valid and that you will respond. This is likely to put you on a "list" where you will get more things like this. It's the flood of other social engineering that becomes the greater risk.

However, there is the risk that you are not prepared for the responses they might bring to bear. They might be better at scaring you and taking control of the situation than you are of resisting it.

My general recommendation is to report this number for what it is: a scammer. There is nothing for you to learn or gain from any interaction.

Comment: My curiosity often gets the best of me. About reporting it, should I report it to Whatsapp or somewhere else? I am thinking of adding the tags brute-force and whatsapp.

Comment: You report to WhatsApp so they can block that number. Neither of those tags are relevant.